# Richtextfield throws validation error if other field fails validation

Tags: magnolia

In my dialog, I have 3 fields, "name", "short description", and "description" which are all mandatory. When I add a new entry, if one of the validation failed in other fields, the richtextfield will always throw error even if it should have passed the validation. In this case, I have value to the description which is a richtext but I dont have value to short description so the validation for this field failed. This only happens on create mode. This does not happen in update mode.
Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Also I notice that the "*" in the label does not show for richtextfield.

[image]

My configuration is:

```
form:
  tabs:
    - name: product
      label: Basic Information
      fields:
       - name: name
         class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
         label: Name
         i18n: true
         required: true
       - name: shortDescription
         class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
         label: Short Description
         rows: 5
         i18n: true
         required: true
       - name: description
         class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.RichTextFieldDefinition
         height: 200
         label: Description
         i18n: true
         required: true
```

Comment: Can you please post your configuration also ?

Comment: @Ducaz035 I edited my post to include my configuration, thanks! Also the mandatory asterisk doesnt show for richtextfield...

Comment: @federico Can this be the cause -> https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-3157

Comment: @Ducaz035 The label for richtextfield is not long. I tried to put few letters only and still the same. Also it's weird that the mandatory validator for richtextfield fails when there's other field error as well. There's 2 different issues encountered here. I don't know if they're bugs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created an issue for that in Magnolia issue tracker

https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-3855

Comment: thanks! How about the other issue about the validation? Are you able to replicate it?

Comment: There seems to be an issue for that as well ; https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-6506